# Matrix of a quadratic form with respect to a basis

Tags: linear-algebra, change-of-basis

"Q$(\left[ {\begin{array}{c}
   x \\
   y \\
  \end{array} } \right] )$ $ = x^2 - xy + y^2$

1. State the symmetric matrix that belongs to Q.
2. "Let $B = \{ \frac 1 {\sqrt{2}}\left[ {\begin{array}{c}
      1 \\
      1 \\
     \end{array} } \right], \frac 1 {\sqrt{2}}\left[ {\begin{array}{c}
      -1 \\
      1 \\
     \end{array} } \right]  \}$ State the matrix that belongs to Q with respect to the basis B. "

I know the answer to question 1 which is: 
$ 
   M=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   1 & -\frac 1{2} \\
   -\frac 1{2} & 1 \\
  \end{array} } \right]
 $

However, I'm completely blank when it comes to question 2. Where do I start?

Comment: I think the matrix is actually $M = \left(\begin{array}{cc} 1 & -1/2 \\ -1/2 & -1 \end{array}\right)$.

Comment: Oh, sorry about that. I made an error and wrote $-y^2$ when it was supposed to be $+y^2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have a vector represented in the standard basis $[x,y]^T$. In your new basis, this same vector is
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left[\begin{matrix}1 & -1 \\ 1 & 1\end{matrix}\right]^T \left[\begin{matrix} x \\ y \end{matrix}\right]$$
So you want
$$\left[\begin{matrix} x \\ y \end{matrix}\right]^TQ_{\text{standard basis}}\left[\begin{matrix} x \\ y \end{matrix}\right]=\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left[\begin{matrix}1 & -1 \\ 1 & 1\end{matrix}\right]^T \left[\begin{matrix} x \\ y \end{matrix}\right]\right)^T Q_{\text{new basis}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left[\begin{matrix}1 & -1 \\ 1 & 1\end{matrix}\right]^T \left[\begin{matrix} x \\ y \end{matrix}\right]$$
$$\left[\begin{matrix} x \\ y \end{matrix}\right]^TQ_{\text{standard basis}}\left[\begin{matrix} x \\ y \end{matrix}\right]=\frac{1}{2}
\left[\begin{matrix} x \\ y \end{matrix}\right]^T\left[\begin{matrix}1 & -1 \\ 1 & 1\end{matrix}\right] 
 Q_{\text{new basis}} \left[\begin{matrix}1 & -1 \\ 1 & 1\end{matrix}\right]^T \left[\begin{matrix} x \\ y \end{matrix}\right]$$
$$Q_{\text{standard basis}}=\frac{1}{2}
\left[\begin{matrix}1 & -1 \\ 1 & 1\end{matrix}\right] 
 Q_{\text{new basis}} \left[\begin{matrix}1 & -1 \\ 1 & 1\end{matrix}\right]^T $$
$$2 \left[\begin{matrix}1 & -1 \\ 1 & 1\end{matrix}\right]^{-1} Q_{\text{standard basis}} \left[\begin{matrix}1 & -1 \\ 1 & 1\end{matrix}\right]^{-T}=
 Q_{\text{new basis}}  $$